# Differences between APP-6A and APP-6B in LuciadMap?

Tags: symbology, luciadmap

I'm using luciadmap 2013.1 and, from what I understood, one can switch between APP-6A and APP-6B symbology like this:

```
new TLcdEditableAPP6AObject(ELcdAPP6Standard.APP_6A)
new TLcdEditableAPP6AObject(ELcdAPP6Standard.APP_6B)
```

Now, I was wondering about the differences between both specifications and I wanted to display a symbol that would look different in APP-6A and APP-6B.

Does anybody know the code of such a symbol? And if it does not exist, then maybe the code of a symbol that appeared in APP-6B.

Answer (score 1):

In the samples provided by Luciad, there are 2 applications that demonstrate the usage of APP-6 APIs:

- symbology.app6a.bat
- symbology.app6b.bat

They both use the exact same objects and I spotted one that looked different. It's a civil aircraft with fixed wings which hierarchy="*1.X.2.3.1*" and symCode="*S*A*CF----******".

Looking at the specifications of APP-6A and APP-6B, one can see that their representation changes a little. In APP-6B the aircraft is filled with the background color whereas it remains white in APP-6A.